# Simplifying POJO to be used by Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a JSON with the following part:

```
{
  "authors": [
    {
      "author": {
        "name": "Foo Bar"
      }
    },
    {
      "author": {
        "name": "Bar Foo"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

It can easilby be mapped to the following DTO:

```
public class Response {

    @SerializedName("authors")
    private List<AuthorsItem> authors;
}

class AuthorsItem {

    @SerializedName("author")
    private Author author;
}

class Author {

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;
}
```

getters/setters omitted for brevity

Is there a way to avoid such a complicated structure and have e.g. `List<Author> authors`? It can be done by writing a class implementing `JsonDeserializer` but this is quite verbose.

Comment: what json you want from POJO, add details in question

Comment: Not sure if I follow. I want a list of `Author` objects. In each `Author` there is only one field - `name`/

Comment: Replace `List<AuthorsItem> authors;` with `List<Author> authors;`

Comment: Sometimes it's easier to keep it all as is. Your classes already reflect the structure of the JSON payloads perfectly, and I don't think it's that bad. Implementing a type adapter (/factory) to be assigned to a certain field of lists with items to be unwrapped may bring more complexity than you think (verbosity is not that bad as you might think).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can only define the Author class and just have the List from where you are accessing the data right? (Maybe as a method in a controller class)

Example: `void saveAuthors(List<Author> authors) {}`

```
class Author {

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;
}
```

Then your JSON would have to be structured as follows.

```
[
  {
     "name": "Foo Bar"
  },
  {
     "name": "Bar Foo"
  }
]
```

When deserializing, you can do the deserialization in a way that it identifies the list correctly.

You can refer to this tutorial for more info: [How to Serialize Deserialize List of Objects in Java? Java Serialization Example](https://crunchify.com/how-to-serialize-deserialize-list-of-objects-in-java-java-serialization-example/)